# Dexie.js: Export and Import Database gives webpack error. Export is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dexie

**Error**

```
index.js:1437 TypeError: _services_indexDB__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default.export is not a function 
        in SaveAndLoad (created by WithStyles(SaveAndLoad))
        in WithStyles(SaveAndLoad) (created by Route)
        in Route (at App.js:94)
        in App (created by Route)
        in Route (created by withRouter(App))
        in withRouter(App) (at src/​index.js:10)
```

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Dexie from "dexie";
import {importDB, exportDB, importInto} from "dexie-export-import";

import db from "../../services/indexDB";

  /*
    let indexedDB = new Dexie("WorkflowMagicUserDB");
       indexedDB.version(1).stores({
         workflows:"++id,client_id,content,title",
         clients:"++id,name",
         calendar_events:"++id,start,end,title,description,client_name,client_id,group_id",
         calendar_event_group_id:"++id, title, client_name, client_id",
         user:"user_id"
    });

    export default indexedDB
*/



import saveAndLoadStyle from '../../PageComponents/SaveAndLoad/style'



function SaveAndLoad(props){

    async function getDB() {
        try {
            const blob = await db.export({ prettyJson: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('' + error);
        }
    };


    getDB()






    return (

       <div>

         some content

       </div>

    )
}



SaveAndLoad.propTypes ={
    classes:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const styles = theme => (saveAndLoadStyle(theme));
export default withStyles(styles)(SaveAndLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the exported standalone functions importDB (), exportDB() and importInto () instead: https://dexie.org/docs/ExportImport/dexie-export-import#usage

Comment: thanks. How do you suggest I convert the blob to JSON? In the link there is a codepen example that uses downloadjs. Should I use that or should I do something else?